# Deny run batch files on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, batch-file, group-policy

I want to deny users on Windows 10 machines I manage the ability to execute .bat files.

I know that I can deny the right to run scripts by GPO or registry, but I'm also running some apps that are started by .bat files on this PC. Is there a way to deny execute privileges for every bat file except my own?

Comment: Make it so the user can only start the applications you want.  You would do that through a group policy, similar approach, to the blacklist approach.

Comment: can it be use also with bat files ?

Comment: .bat files are opened with cmd, so you really can just alter the registry item for .bat and .cmd files. But whatever solution you go for, it will block ALL .bat and .cmd files respectively, including the ones you don't want to block. The whitelist approach would work better in that regard.

Comment: ok then, different way. is any posibility to convert bat file to run with blocked script running in gpo ?